# Python for loop as variable name

Tags: python, loops, variables

I got the following for loop in Python:

```
for x in ["a","b","c"]:
```

Inside this loop, I'm defining a data frame that includes a, b, and c in their name: df_a, df_b, df_c. I also need those a, b, and c for calculations, say, a+1, etc.

At the end of this loop, I want to print the number of observations in each data frame: df_a.shape[0], etc.

Can anyone address me on how to do this?

Comment: Don't. Use a dictionary to index your objects, not variable names.

Comment: `dfs = [df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d]`, then `for x in dfs:`.

Comment: `dictionary = {'a': df_a, 'b': df_b, 'c': df_c}  # map names with dataframes`

`for name, df in dictionary.items():`
        `print("name :" + name)`
        `print("Dataframe length =" + df.shape[0])`